# Purpose and workflow of wireframe models

Tags: 2d-graphics, model, pixel-graphics

I am more less familiarized with the major computer graphics concepts up to certain dregree of "low-levelness". So I know how models, vertices, polygons etc. and how these works. Also how is the info in these (meaning the models) serialized and interpreted by a software, generally a game or graphics engine, to use this models info, vertices and indices, to get the model itself and handle it accordingly.

Thats why I was surprised when I found some [wireframe models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-frame_model), because I am not familiar neither with the concept nor the purpose of these.

1.- Are these handled (seralized and de-serialized) same as regular vertices models? Back in the beginning of computer graphics guess this was about all a computer could easily do, but is there any other purpose?

2.- If there is a wireframe resource provided such as [this](https://www.spriters-resource.com/pc_computer/starcraft/sheet/59990/), how it would me used/handled. In the case of a 2D isometric view game, I do not know what would I need to do with resources provided in this format. What would be roughly the approach? There are no vertices in this case, the wireframe is provided as a sprite resource, so what is it that needs to be done roughly to make use of it?

I am not after an specific algorithm to handle this, this is not a code question. I mean what would be the general concept/workflow for this type of resource.

Comment: You should split this into 2 separate questions.

Comment: Agreeing with @joojaa. It would be better to edit out the second question and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why are wireframes used?

   - Games don't really use wireframes much, but they might be useful for HUD items etc.
   - Asset creators, designers and engineers use wireframes to see whats inside objects. TO clarify the edged between elements or to preview unimportant aspects.

     [image]

     **Image 1**: Different 3D views (click to zoom)

     Engineers and Architects also may have very complex pure line drawings, with millions of lines and they would like to have them accelerated. (Imagine having each brick in one layer for a shopping mall, along with lines for each strut, electrical wire bundle, each air and plumbing pipe and each furniture in one drawing.) Nothing kills productivity like having a sluggish CAD response.
   - Selection highlight etc.

     [image]

     **Image 2**: Edge loop Selected and highlighted

   **Note**: Gamer card drivers don't frequently have, or have lacking wireframe acceleration routines, while the workstation versions of the cards do.
2. How are wireframes drawn?

   Same way as polygons, or just as lists of points to be joined
3. *"If there is a wireframe resource provided such as this, how it would me used/handled. In the case of a 2D isometric view game, I do not know what would I need to do with resources provided in this format."*

   its not a wireframe. Its a sprite sheet. Don't confuse the technical meaning of wireframe in computer graphics and how ui designers use the word to mean different things.

   Presumably your game engine has a method for defining sprite sheets. Otherwise you would just use a shader to make them.

   Its not really related to the body of the question you asked should be separated into a different question.

Comment: How are wireframes drawn? Same way as polygons, or just as lists of points to be joined -> so nothing changes in the information handling right? vertex and indexes are handled, then the wires would be drawn normally, with a shader for example, right?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay well except they arent triangles.

Comment: regarding the answer to point 3., what is the point of a wireframe spritesheet then? I get it would be manipulated the same as a normal sprite, but just to be rendered as is (a wireframe sprite) in the game, nothing else, correct?

Comment: well except they arent triangles -> but vertices arranged in a buffer as always, right?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay ask the original artist. Meybe they were looking into certain astethics.

Comment: regarding 1. Models can be normal vertex models where the wireframe is drawn or highlighted with a shader. I know that that task can be  done. My point/here is if there are serializable models that are passed around between softwares as wireframe models or all the models are the same (vertices + indices) and when shaded/rendered you have the wireframe model rendered as such, but internally, the serializable data is just a current/normal model. Maybe I am overthinking this. Hope I make myself understood

Comment: I refer to the model in my question to the serialiazble data of the model, not the rendered in the screen model, that is interpreted by a software + shader effects added

Comment: so my point is if there are wireframe models serialized and handled as such by softwares different from the normal vertices + indices models

Comment: @rustyBucketBay there is no one way to handle polygons, and theres on one way to handle line constructs. Yes you can just dump a normal polygo model and get the thing wireframe rendered. But you dont need to do this you can also do it differently since lines arent triangles. Just like there ate many ways to draw polygons. But yes the pipeline is either exactly the same or similar enough for saying ist handled the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding wireframes as an edge list.

Wireframe models are used in engineering and CAD they provide several benefits. The Wikipedia page you linked has some benefits, this [AutoCAD page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-84E193D7-A18D-4EE2-B978-19E4AFBCAEEC-htm.html) has some more. Wireframe are used less in games and movies since they are generally more concerned about the visuals and wireframes are more concerned about design (form over function).  But wireframes can be converted for rasterization and will get used in games/movies but so far as I have seen are converted (to the appropriate format) first, ( I am going to guess that there are games that use wireframe almost exclusively, but I haven't had the pleasure...knock on wood)

The source you linked in the second question is not a edge list wire frame since there is no source for the edges provided. Sprites drawn as a wireframe are yet another thing again, usually the background is clear and the sprite is drawn over another sprite to give it an outline. Such as when it is selected or a mouse if hovering over it.

Games and most rendering tools overload the term "wireframe" when referring to a triangle mesh drawn as lines without filling the triangles, sometimes drawn as quads, again just as lines. This is not the same thing as a wire frame model either since a wireframe model is comprised edge lists.

Comment: So now a I dont know neither how Sprites drawn as a wireframe are handled or what is their purpose XD. I was looking for a more specific info in the concrete questions I make, anyhow you comments are very useful, thank you for the answer